# Get a list of settings on Android device

Tags: android

I would like to get a list of all settings on the Android device. That is Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, Sound, Display,... Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Most of what you search are in the PackageManager : Try `getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH);`
Check this page in order to have some other information : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html. 
it's not really the list you want but I hope it help you.

Comment: I'm already using PackageManager for other things but I don't see anything for settings. I know Gesture search can do it.